# Mysql workbench rollback not returning the table to last commit?

Tags: mysql-workbench

I'm using the rollback command to go to the previous commit but it doesn't seem to work.

I have tried executing the query multiple time and making sure that I didn't commit again but it doesn't work. I have copied the db from another table. I've executed the command as a block and as a whole but the result remains the same.

```
INSERT INTO departments_dup
select * from departments;

COMMIT;

UPDATE departments_dup
SET
    dept_no = 'd011',
    dept_name = 'Quality Control';

select * from departments_dup;

ROLLBACK;
```

The table should get back to its previous state but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: This isn't how rollback in MySQL works, and "commit" does not mean the same thing in MySQL as in Git.  `ROLLBACK` here means return the table to the state in which it was before the update, should an error occur.

Comment: I copied the data to the departments_dup and then used the command commit. Then I messed up the newly created table with the update statement. Now I want the table as it was at the time of commit, so I used rollback. Am I missing something?

Comment: `ROLLBACK` only has a memory of the transaction being executed.  Once a transaction finishes successfully, you are stuck with the new state of your data.

Comment: I ended up here by having EXACTLY the same issue as you with my departments_dup (five months later). I also was confused because it did not work the way I expected. Then I found that set autocommit = 0; solved the issue. It turns out that MySql starts the session for each connection with autocommit enabled. This means that SQL commits after each statement that did return an error. I found this link helpfull:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-autocommit-commit-rollback.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use auto-commit before executing **ROLLBACK** or **COMMIT**. It worked perfectly for me.

```
set autocommit = 0;

INSERT INTO departments_dup
select * from departments;

COMMIT;

UPDATE departments_dup
SET
dept_no = 'd011',
dept_name = 'Quality Control';

select * from departments_dup;

ROLLBACK;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your database tables were created using MyISAM, you will need to backup your database, do a find and replace 'MyISAM' to 'InnoDB' in your backup file and then restore your database.